# Sharing Videos On Facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube

I've been looking at facebook pages whos primary function is to share 'the best videos on the internet' with their viewers and I'm interested in exactly how they get their material. I've looked at the source of some of these videos and it appears as though they are hosted on facebook servers. Obviously these pages are not downloading this content from youtube and re-uploading it to facebook as this is an infringement of the youtube copyright user policy so i'm wondering how is it that these pages manage to share these pages are able to embed these videos in their pages so that they play directly on the users timeline (i don't want to share a link to youtube)

Comment: When they _are_ “hosted on facebook servers”, then obviously someone has uploaded them to there before. // Embedding videos in _external_ URLs, so that they are playable inline in newsfeed/timeline, is done via Open Graph meta tags. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

Comment: Thank you i think thats exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: OK, I added an answer, plus some additional info.

Answer (score 2):

Embedding videos in *external* URLs, so that they are playable inline in newsfeed/timeline, is done via Open Graph meta tags.

Which tags you need specifically for videos, you’ll find described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

To test your implementation, you can use Facebook’s debug tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

You can embed either `swf` flash players, or `mp4` videos directly.

Be aware, that you need an HTTPS version of the resources you want to embed, otherwise they won’t be playable inline, the browser will block them.